# How can I fixbut does not contain package golang.org/x/sys?

Tags: go

Minimal reproducible example: https://play.golang.org/p/saGt7CYOsm4

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/sys"
)

func main() {
}
```

```
go: finding module for package golang.org/x/sys
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200610111108-226ff32320da
prog.go:4:2: module golang.org/x/sys@latest found (v0.0.0-20200610111108-226ff32320da), but does not contain package golang.org/x/sys
```

This is probably a general problem with the sys package but I run into it when importing [testcontainers-go](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go):

```
        github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go imports
        github.com/docker/docker/pkg/archive imports
        golang.org/x/sys/execabs: module golang.org/x/sys@latest found (v0.0.0-20210421221651-33663a62ff08, replaced by golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20180810173357-98c5dad5d1a0), but does not contain package golang.org/x/sys/execabs
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! What method would you like to use of sys?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241582/unable-to-get-the-package-from-the-module):   The application should import the packages within the module, not the root of the module (there are no Go files at the root of the module).

Answer (score 1):

`golang.org/x/sys` is not a valid package, as can be seen here [1]. If
you look at your own output, you will notice that the other module actually
imports `golang.org/x/sys/execabs` [2]. Working example:

```
package main

import (
   "golang.org/x/sys/execabs"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   c := execabs.Command("go", "version")
   c.Stdout = os.Stdout
   c.Run()
}
```

1. https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys
2. https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/execabs